# Where in Amsterdam can one legally spray graffiti?

Tags: legal, netherlands, amsterdam

My friend is an artist and she wondered if she can draw on the walls in Amsterdam legally and if yes where?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

No it is not legal (not just Amsterdam, but everywhere). Some municipalities have 'walls of fame' [where it is legal](http://www.geelblauw.nl/waar-kan-ik-legaal-graffiti-spuiten-in-nederland/). (They are sometimes called 'Hall of fame' (HOF)).

[Here is a map](https://www.google.com/maps/d/viewer?ll=52.10650500000001%2C5.075684000000024&spn=2.699264%2C7.415771&t=m&msa=0&z=7&source=embed&ie=UTF8&iwloc=000454be896d0b7bbfd3f&mid=1sN3i3g3JJo7u-PmTrglTP4Smjkw) of them, but I have no idea how up-to-date this is. It mentions one under the Schellingwouderbrug (near Flevopark) in Amsterdam, but it's current status is unknown.

Website [legal-walls.net](https://legal-walls.net/) also mentions some Amsterdam locations (again mentioning the [Flevopark](https://legal-walls.net/wall/269) - read the comments), but again, no guarantees here. In The Netherlands we sometimes have the tendency to tolerate things that are officially forbidden.

[Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Amsterdam/comments/29xghq/does_anyone_know_of_any_legal_graffiti_walls_in/) on the subject.

Note that the [fine for graffiti in The Netherlands is € 140.=](https://www.om.nl/onderwerpen/boetebase/?boete_tree=21968,21919#beslissingpad2196821919).

Comment: It could be legal if the building is private and the owner allows it.

Comment: @JonathanReez I tried to find anything 'official' regarding that, but was unable to. You are right to say *could*, because there are still rules about the visual effects on the neighbourhood (look up *Welstandscommissie*). This even goes so far that in the reverse situation (illegal graffitti) on a private building, the owner has to give permission to have it removed *unless the graffiti is offensive* (then it will be removed *without* the owner's permission) (IIRC I read that in Utrecht regulations).

Comment: @JonathanReez could, but very improbable. Indeed, see welstandscommissie. (A backyard facing wall could be legal, a street facing wall is almost always illegal unless you have the right paperwork.) And a lot of the buildings in Amsterdam are monuments, where no graffiti is allowed at all.

Comment: @JonathanReez as a broad, general, rule - even if you have the "owner's permission" things like graffiti are not allowed (as a rule) in Europe, certainly in any old towns, which are generally totally protected.  Typically you can't even, say, paint your window frames some particular color, it is all completely controlled.  The idea of "going to Europe to do graffiti" is just generally a non-starter.

Comment: @JoeBlow you can do whatever you want if the wall isn't facing the street and far from all of Amsterdam consists of historic buildings.

Comment: legal-walls.net seems about as specifically succinct of an answer as you could ask for considering most of probably never even conceptualized the idea of legal graffiti walls before this question